# how to create a 2D vector: first row of string and second row is integer

Tags: c++, vector

how can i make a vector where the first row is of string and second row is of integers ?
where each number represents number of occurence of each word

Example:

```
this adam dad hello
 2    4    1    6
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some possibilities.

If you care for the order of the elements:

```cpp
vector<pair<string, int>> occurrences;

int main(){
    occurrences.push_back( make_pair("this", 2) );
    occurrences.push_back( make_pair("adam", 4) );
    //access: occurrences[0].first or occurrences[0].second
}
```

---

Otherwise:

```cpp
map<string, int> occurrences;             //O(logN) insertion and lookup
```

```cpp
unordered_map<string, int> occurrences;   //O(1) insertion and lookup
```

```cpp
int main(){
    occurrences["this"] = 2;
    occurrences["adam"] = 4;
}
```

---

If you want something elaborated, you can use `struct`:

```cpp
struct occurrence{
    string word;
    int value;
    occurrence(){}
    occurrence(string w, int v){word = w; value = v;}
};

occurrence ocurrences[10];

int main(){
    ocurrences[0] = ocurrence("this", 2);
    ocurrences[1] = ocurrence("adam", 4);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I find it most convenient to create a vector of `struct` ... or, as the case may be, classes.  One field is the name; the other is the count.  Access by e.g. `vector[n].word` or `vector[n].wordCount`.  The virtue of this approach is that it's easy to add more fields at any time.